# Seaborn lineplot: how to match error band edge linestyle to main line linestyle

Tags: python, seaborn, line-plot

I am using Seaborn to make lineplots with an error band indicating full distribution of measurements and making use of the Style grouping variable. As the plotted groups are overlapping, it is not fully clear to which main line the error bands belong

[image: see plot here]

I would like to make this more clear by matching the linestyle of the error bands edges to the linestyle of the main line, but cannot find how to fix this.

The [plot demonstrating grouping variables (see plot here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uhRA.png) on [Seaborns Lineplot instructional page](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html) illustrates the problem as well. By entering the two different linestyles keywords *err_kws={'linestyle': [(0,(1,1)),'solid']}* congruent to the grouping variable specific main line linestyle definition *dashes={'cue':(), 'stim':(1,1)}* (in codeblock below) I tried to adjust the error band edge linestyle, but the first listed linestyle adjustment is then applied to all error band edges, while the second listed error band linestyle specification remains unused.

```
fmri = sns.load_dataset("fmri")
sns.relplot(data=fmri, x="timepoint", y="signal", size="region", style="event",
         dashes={'cue':(), 'stim':(1,1)}, err_kws={'linestyle': [(0,(1,1)),'solid']},
         kind="line")
```

I would like to have [the groups with solid main line with solid error band edge (see plot here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQFaz.png), while [the groups with dotted main line should have a dotted error band edge (see plot here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enlcr.png).

I also tried to call the main line style variable *kws["dashes"]*, that is defined in Seaborns code in for Relational Plots (relational.py, line 513-518), by passing err_kws={'linestyle': 'kws["dashes"]', but this did not work either.

```
if "style" in sub_vars:
            attributes = self._style_map(sub_vars["style"])
            if "dashes" in attributes:
                kws["dashes"] = attributes["dashes"]
            if "marker" in attributes:
                kws["marker"] = attributes["marker"]
```

Is it possible to base the error band linestyle on the main line linestyle in a Seaborn lineplot?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Maybe `ax = plt.gca(); for poly, line in zip(ax.collections, ax.lines): poly.set_linestyle(line.get_linestyle())`

Comment: @JohanC Thanks! Your answer seems to work under the condition that only the first 'standard' linestyles in Seaborn figures are used, as get_linestyle() returns '--' for all non-solid lines, instead of the specific length dimensions within the dash (on_off_)sequence.
I finally manage to plot how I want the figures to be with the code

`plt.setp(poly, linewidth=line._linewidth, linestyle=(0.0, (None if line._dashSeq is None else (np.array(line._dashSeq)/(line._linewidth)).tolist())))`

Comment: You might add your solution as an answer and accept it. That could help future visitors with the same question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally manage to plot how I want the figures to be with the code

```
ax = plt.gca()
for poly, line in zip(ax.collections, ax.lines):
    plt.setp(
        poly,
        linewidth=line._linewidth,
        linestyle=(
            0.0,
            (
                None
                if line._dashSeq is None
                else (np.array(line._dashSeq) / (line._linewidth)).tolist()
            ),
        ),
    )
```

Here is the final plot

[image: Here is the final plot]